AuthenticationFailed while calling azure api
I am using an react app to call azure apis. This is how it is setup:
import { BrowserAuthError, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider, useMsal, AuthenticatedTemplate, UnauthenticatedTemplate } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { msalConfig } from './authConfig';

const pca = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.Read"],
};

const response = await instance.acquireTokenPopup(loginRequest);
const accessToken = response.accessToken;
const fetchResponse = await fetch('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/<rg>/providers/Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/<afd>?api-version=2021-06-01', {
headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
},
});
const data = await fetchResponse.json();

This is what I have in authConfig
const msalConfig = {
auth: {
    clientId: <clientId>,
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>`,
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
},
cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
},
};

I have configured the following permissions in the app and I also created a service principal and gave it contributor access to the subscription. I am able to get the token using this code but using that token is resulting in
{
"error": {
    "code": "AuthenticationFailed",
    "message": "Authentication failed."
}
} 

Am I missing any step here?

On adding the azure service management API permissions, I am being asked for admin approval.


This is the enterprise applications settings:




have you tried adding Azure Service Management delegated permissions

please clone javascript app,

Tried adding the Azure service management user_impersonation delegated permission too. Still getting the same error.
@logeshpalani31: Can you point me to the app that you are talking about?

Initially I created a Microsoft Entra ID application and added API permissions like below:

I added contributor role to Service Principal as you:

When I tried to access the API, I got the similar error as you:


The error usually occurs if the required API permissions are not granted to the Microsoft Entra ID application.
To resolve the error, you need to add Azure Service Management delegated API permission like below:

And in the code pass scope as https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation like
scopes: ["https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation"]

I am able to fetch the API results successfully as below:

const pca = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

function FetchDataComponent() {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const loginRequest = {
        scopes: ["https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation"],
    };

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await instance.acquireTokenPopup(loginRequest);
            const accessToken = response.accessToken;
            const fetchResponse = await fetch('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/ruk/providers/Microsoft.Network/frontDoors?api-version=2019-05-01', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                },
            });

            if (!fetchResponse.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${fetchResponse.status}`);
            }

            const data = await fetchResponse.json();
            setData(data);
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={fetchData}>Fetch Data</button>
            {error && <p>Error: {error}</p>}
            {data && <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>}
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <MsalProvider instance={pca}>
            <AuthenticatedTemplate>
                <FetchDataComponent />
            </AuthenticatedTemplate>
            <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
                <p>Please sign in to see the data.</p>
            </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        </MsalProvider>
    );
}

export default App;



As I do not have any front door I got empty output:


Thank you so much! Unfortunately, when I add azure service management and change the scope, at the login page I am seeing this error "Need admin approval
needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.". This is strange because the API permission page clears says that Admin consent is not required.

Can you paste the screen shot of the consent and permissions settings under the Enterprise applications

added the screen shots in the original question since I can't do it in the comments

Go to Enterprise applications -> Consent and permissions -> User consent settings and paste the screenshot

I apologize. Added it now.

@PradeepVairamani Can you also paste Admin consent settings page screenshot?

added that as well

One last screenshot of permission classification too:) @PradeepVairamani

Done. And thanks again for all the help!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
